# Accessing CSS styling with JavaScript when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a class assignment I need to position an image of a square, either left, right or center depending on which corresponding radio button I click.

I wish to keep as much styling out of JavaScript as I can. However this is proving a problem as I am unable to access what I want. Example:

This is one of the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="center" name="position" onclick=moveShape() value="center">center
```

The shape itself:

```
<span id="square">
</span>
```

its JavaScript:

```
function moveShape() {
    var center = document.getElementById("center");
    var shape = document.getElementById("square");
    if(center.checked){
        // access CSS here

    }
```

and then I want to access styling, such as:

```
        #somenewid {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
       // code to center it

    }
```

I have tried setting a new id. Such as `shape.id = "cent";` which works once, but if I then click another radio button and come back to the center button, it tells me the ID is null.

I do not, and cannot, be given the answer to the assignment but I do need to know how to set my HTML/JavaScript elements such that I am able to access CSS styling.

Comment: You can get styles applied to an element by doing something like: ```window.getComputedStyle(element)``` in your case that would be ```window.getComputedStyle(shape)``` more information on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: would that enable me to assign different styles to the 3 elements; left, right and center?

Comment: assigning different styles can be done by adding a ```style``` attribute to the element ```shape.setAttribute("style", "left: 10px; top: 20px");```

Comment: @Varinder I think it's better to manipulate the `style` **property** directly: `shape.style.left = '10px';`

Comment: @mpen yup, many ways to skin a cat, however it may be easier to apply all styles in one giant string

Comment: Is it from your assignment that you have to do it through js, or because you don't know the :checked css pseudo-class selector?

Comment: @Varinder I guess I was just weary of doing it that way because I've had bad experiences in the past trying to get properties like "checked" via `getAttribute` but upon further research it seems the only downside of setting the style this way is that it'll overwrite any inline styles you set in the HTML. It should perhaps be noted though that you can still set multiple styles via `Object.assign(shape.style, {left:'10px',top:'20px'})` but I guess it doesn't matter how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to "center" the shape relative to, but this should get you started:

```js
function moveShape(cb) {

  let square = document.getElementById('square');
  if (cb.checked) {
    square.className = "center";
  } else {
    square.className = "right";
  }
}
```

```css
#square {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="checkbox" onChange="moveShape(this)"> center
</label>

<div class="container">
  <span id="square" class="right"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. OP "*wish to keep as much styling out of JavaScript as [they] can*".

Comment: @Kaiido Good point. Updated my answer. Yours is still better though.

Comment: Just noticed he used "checkbox" in the question title but a "radio" in his HTML. Oh well. Now we have examples of both ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to reinvent is the [`class` attribute/selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

You can add/remove this attribute as you wish, and add multiple of these, allowing you to assign different style rules more dynamically.

In the following example, I'll use the container `text-align` property to set the shape's alignment, so I'll add the class to this container element.

```js
// we will add the event listeners to all the input elements
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(inp) {
  inp.addEventListener('change', moveShape);
});

function moveShape(evt) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var pos = this.value;
  // first we remove the previous classes
  container.classList.remove('left', 'center', 'right');
  // then we add the new one
  container.classList.add(pos);
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#square {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#container.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#container.left {
  text-align: left;
}

#container.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="left" name="position" value="left" name="shape-pos" checked><label for="left">left</label>
<input type="radio" id="center" name="position" value="center" name="shape-pos"><label for="center">center</label>
<input type="radio" id="right" name="position" value="right" name="shape-pos"><label for="right">right</label>

<div id="container">
  <span id="square">
</span>
</div>
```

But all this could be done without js, thanks to the [`input:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#square {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#left:checked ~ #container {
  text-align: left;
}

#center:checked ~ #container {
  text-align: center;
}

#right:checked ~ #container {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="left" name="position" value="left" name="shape-pos" checked><label for="left">left</label>
<input type="radio" id="center" name="position" value="center" name="shape-pos"><label for="center">center</label>
<input type="radio" id="right" name="position" value="right" name="shape-pos"><label for="right">right</label>

<div id="container">
  <span id="square">
</span>
</div>
```